# Twilio security PIN for conference call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I am using twilio gem for making calls in my rails app. Everything is working fine, now I want to add a conference functionality(adding conference functionality is easy) which should ask for pin before joining call, I don't want to add PIN logic manually. If suppose I will add code for entering PIN, how twilio will work to add all those clients to conference who entered PIN correctly. Does twilio support any thing like this? Any body have any idea about this kind of functionality?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/07/easy-conference-calling-twilio.html

Comment: @usha thanks for the link, I have already seen this link  yesterday but I want to know how twilio will work to add all those clients to conference who will enter PIN correctly, what methods I can use, what response twilio give give back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The URL that usha shared is a good start for adding PIN functionality for conferences. There's no automatic way to do it, you need to use a combination of [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) and your own logic for the correct PIN to make this work.

In Rails that might look a bit like this:

Initial webhook for incoming calls to the conference number:

```
def start_conference
  response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
  response.gather(:action => conference_gather_url, :num_digits => 4) do |gather|
    gather.say("Please enter the code for the conference", :voice => 'alice')
  end
  return :xml => response.to_xml
end
```

In this example, when the user enters 4 digits the call will automatically cause a request to the `conference_gather_url` with the digits that were entered sent as the `Digits` parameter in the body of the request.

Then the action needs to check that the PIN is correct and allow access to the conference if it is. I have included a `pin_is_correct?` method below, it is up to you to implement this.

```
def conference_gather
  pin = params["Digits"]
  response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
  if pin_is_correct?(pin)
    response.dial do |dial|
      dial.conference("CONFERENCE_NAME")
    end
  else
    response.say("Your pin was incorrect. Goodbye.")
    response.hangup
  end
  return :xml => response.to_xml
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.